# Applying new UI to JInternalFrame title

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I've never done anything with UI's before and I've been tasked with getting our internal frame titles changed.  We're using the Nimbus L&F and in our UI manager I've tried

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrameTitlePane.background", Color.RED);
```

just to try and get something to change.  The didn't work for me and I found another post somewhere about creating a UI using the BasicInternalFrameTitlePane so I now have this code:

```
public class CFrameTitleUI extends BasicInternalFrameTitlePane {

    public CFrameTitleUI(JInternalFrame f)
    {
        super(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintTitleBackground(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

But now that I have this I'm not sure what to do with it.  I've tried setting the UI in the internal frame using it's `setUI()` method, but this is a title bar for it so I'm sure thats wrong.  I next tried

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrameTitlePane.background", CFrameTitleUI.getClass().getName());
```

and

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrameTitlePane", CFrameTitleUI.getClass().getName());
```

but nothing.  Do I need to tie it back to the nimbus L&F somehow?  Some of the things we're setting say `"nimbusSelection"` etc..

Main questions are am I creating a custom UI for the internal frame titles correctly and how do I apply it, thanks.

Comment: Does changing the UI manager value for `InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane[Enabled].textForeground` do anything for you? If you want to change the background it's more complicated because it's a gradient paint and I'm not sure how the rest of the border if affected.

Comment: @user1803551 Didn't change anything it still used the default font.

Comment: Let's start on even footing. I posted a code in an answered along with what I get. It's not an answer, but the code is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same?

[image]

```
public class InternalFrameTest extends JFrame {

    public InternalFrameTest() {

        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("AHHHH!!!!", true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setOpaque(false);
        desktop.add(frame);
        setContentPane(desktop);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimbusLookAndFeel.class.getName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException|InstantiationException
                |IllegalAccessException|UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        UIManager.put("InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane[Enabled].textForeground", Color.RED);
        new InternalFrameTest();
    }
}
```

When I run (without setting anything to it)

```
System.out.println(UIManager.getColor("InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane[Enabled].textForeground"));
```

I get

```
"DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145"
```

Do you get the same?

Comment: Did the exact same code but my title bar has black text still.  We're still using Java 6 in a MAC environment though and based on your catch you're at least on 7.  So maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I changed my compiler compliance level to 1.6 and I still get the same result. I took the LAF from `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus` (1.6) and not from `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus` (1.7). Is it the same path for you? Additionally, Nimbus is platform independent. The only thing I can find is in a note in the tutorial `not all versions or implementations of Java SE 6 support Nimbus`, although you say Nimbus does load for you. Try my supplement to the above post.

Comment: My import is com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus and the output is DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145  placing the same output after putting it into the UIManager says the color is red, just for some reason it's not showing up as it.

Comment: OK, let's go higher. Set `UIManager.put("text", Color.RED);` or `UIManager.put("control", Color.RED);`. Anything?

Comment: First one made the text red, second one made the background of the content area red.

Comment: At least that's something. Can't you switch to Java 7? There's backwards compatibility anyway.

Comment: We do plan on switching to a more recent version but right now we're one week away from a major product release and demo, so we're just playing safe for now.  Getting the title backgrounds to change or the title fonts would be nice but it's not going to make or break us.  Thanks for all your help on this though @user1803551.

Comment: Well, if you can install Java 7 on one of your machines in addition and check the code then it would give a hint as to where the problem originates without affecting your current code.